# how i can refresh only the "select" data

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, select, refresh

I have a select one called regions, when choosing a region the commutables select is activated to be able to choose one in relation to the select regions, all this is read from a database by mySql, the problem is that at Load the "commune" data, all the other values ​​in the form are lost, how can I do that to only reload the select? first of all, Thanks.
i leave my code here.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <a><label for="cmbRegiones" class="sr-only">Region</label></a>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cmbComunas" name="cmbComunas" disabled="true" placeholder="Region">
  <select name="cmbRegiones" class="form-control"  onchange="comunas(this)">
    <option>Seleccione una Region</option>                                    
    <%
       ConeBD cn4 = new ConeBD();
       String region1 = request.getParameter("id");
       if (region1 == null) {
         try {
           ResultSet poi = cn4.consultarRegion();
           while (poi.next()) {
             out.print("<option value='" + poi.getInt(1) + "'>" + poi.getString(2) + "</option>");
           }
         } catch (Exception e) {
           out.print(e.toString());
         }
       } else {
         try {
           ResultSet poi = cn4.consultarRegion(region1);
           while (poi.next()) {
             out.print("<option value='" + poi.getInt(1) + "' selected>" + poi.getString(2) + "</option>");
           }
           ResultSet poi2 = cn4.consultarRegion2(region1);
           while (poi2.next()) {
             out.print("<option value='" + poi2.getInt(1) + "'>" + poi2.getString(2) + "</option>");
           }
         } catch (Exception e) {
           out.print(e.toString());
         }
       }
     %>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: which are you working with, JavaScript or Java, you tagged both in your question? If it is JavaScript, have a look at how to make an Ajax call to only return the relevant data and bind it each time you change an option in the select.

Comment: Sorry for that, tag java because I'm working on that language and I thought it was relevant to the script, and thanks for replying I'll see how I make it work in ajax